# How can I convert a double value into a datetime?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a class that converts the current time to some specific time that's specified in web.config, like adding  2.30 or 2.45 to the current time.

Here is my class:

```
Public Shared Function GetGoTime() As DateTime
    Dim hrs = Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Gotime"))  
    Dim GoTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(hrs)
    Return GoTime
End Function
```

This works fine when we are adding an integer, but when we add something like 2.45 or 7.37 hours, then it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse the hours and minutes separately by splitting the given time by `.` and then use  `AddMinutes` function by calculating the value in minutes for hours by multiplying it by 60, something like,

```
Dim hrs = ...your code only to extract the hours;
Dim minutes = ...your code only to extract only the minutes;
Dim GoTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(hrs*60 + minutes);
```

Comment: Thnks for quick answer and if we want only the time part then we can use  GoTime.ToLongTimeString()  in my case i want that

Answer (score 1):

What about to use [TimeSpan.FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan.fromhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
Public Shared Function GetGoTime() As DateTime
    Dim hrs = Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Gotime"))  
    Dim GoTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(hrs))
    Return GoTime
End Function
```